# How to convert from Timestamp to com.websudos.phantom.dsl.DateTime or set the current time

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax, phantom-dsl

I am using phantom 1.29.4 and scala 2.11.8, trying to do hands on cassandra with scala. I have my datamodel like below...

```
    case class User(id: Long, name: String, createdDate: Timestamp, ...)
    class UserTableMapping extends CassandraTable[UserTableDao, User] {
        ...
        object createdDate extends DateTimeColumn(this)
        ...
    }

    abstract class UserTableDao extends UserTableMapping with RootConnector {
        def createUser(user: User) = insert.value...(_.createdDate, user.createdDate)
        ...
    }
```

Now, I am getting a type mismatch error ("expected com.websudos.phantom.dsl.DateTime actual java.sql.Timestamp" which is obvious)... Now my question is how do I convert Timestamp to DateTime (because, I have my service layer in different sub project and I don want to add all phantom dsl jars there) or provide current time to Datetime?

I have also tried providing a implicit conversion like below...

```
    implicit def sqlTimestampToPhantomDateTime(dt: Timestamp): DateTime = new DateTime(dt)
```

but still no luck...

Please help me guys as I am new to cassandra... Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats just a [joda DateTime](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/com/websudos/phantom-dsl_2.11/1.29.4/phantom-dsl_2.11-1.29.4-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#com.websudos.phantom.dsl.package@DateTime=org.joda.time.DateTime):

```
type DateTime = org.joda.time.DateTime
```

The joda DateTime has a [millisecond constructor](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html), so you're almost there. All you need to do is get the timestamp in millis from your `Timestamp` instance and use it to construct a `DateTime` instance:

```
new DateTime(timestampInstance.getTime, DateTimeZone.UTC)
```

However you can also just create a new DateTime instance with to have the current time:

```
new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)
```

---

**Edit**: For anybody reading this in the future, @flavian makes a valid point in how phantom handles timezones, I edited this one to reflect it.

Comment: Yeah... I saw that type in package object... But never thought of the long constructor :P Nevertheless thanks a lot for opening my eyes man... :D

Comment: @ArunavaS Don't use the single argument long constructor, read my suggestion first. I'm sure about it as I'm the one who wrote phantom :)

Comment: @flavian, thank you for the point... Actually for now, it seems working with DateColumn should work and I am continuing with the same... But, I shall keep in consideration the point in future :)..

Comment: @flavian, Also, I am getting an error from idea ide... should I need to add sbt plugin?

Comment: @flavian, 
Line I have: object contactPhones extends JsonListColumn[ContactPhone](this)

Error by idea IDE: **Not Applicable** for "**(this)**"

Comment: @ArunavaS That's because Intelij is crap with Scala :) it's the best one around still, which is pretty sad.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer is correct in saying that phantom just uses Joda Time by default, but it introduces a rather dangerous suggestion of using a `new DateTime()` empty param constructor, which will use the local timezone of the machine where it's executing.

By default, phantom enforces a `DateTimeZone.UTC` when it parses back from Cassandra, because Cassandra only deals with UTC time for the `timestamp` type.

So you have to use `new Datetime(time, DateTimeZone.UTC)` to make sure you get the same thing back from Cassandra as what you put in.

Comment: Good point, that slipped by me. This should be the accepted answer, however since its (currently) not I edited mine to point it out.